# Align a parent div block to bottom

Tags: html, css

Consider the following `HTML`:

```
<div style="height:250px; background-color: aqua;">
    <div id="i">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

and css-styles:

```
#i{
    position:relative;
    font-style:italic;
    color: navy;
    text-align:right;
    bottom:0;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/hLZpz/). I'm expected that `div#i` will be at the bottom right corner. Why it's not true and how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Change `position` to `absolute`

```
<div style="height:250px; background-color: aqua;position:relative">
    <div id="i">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

```
#i{
    position:absolute;
    font-style:italic;
    color: navy;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/hLZpz/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to set relative positioning on the parent div and then absolute positioning on the child (as well as setting the bottom and right to zero).

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/hLZpz/6/)**

```
<div style="height:250px; background-color: aqua;position:relative;">
    <div id="i">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>

#i{
    position:absolute;
    font-style:italic;
    color: navy;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table`, `display: table-cell`, and `vertical-align: bottom`.

No need for absolute positioning.

### HTML

```html
<div id="h">
    <div id="i">
        Some text
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
#h
{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 250px;
    background-color: aqua;
}

#i
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    text-align: right;
    font-style: italic;
    color: navy;
}
```

### ***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/y6Za9/)***